# scatterplot of a series of column data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter

here is my dataframe:

```
well    oldFixed    plusFixed   plusEDR
1   2.915592074 2.910839208 2.862335889
2   3.323318766 3.383263286 3.347622461
3   4.945145873 5.021197126 4.988297921
4   1.854648587 1.95118628  1.920797241
5   1.571283325 1.661679772 1.633379863
6   0.640947278 0.635513829 0.628581022
7   2.320205739 2.428897777 2.478926599
8   1.419064296 1.491316432 1.46810657
9   0.802305835 0.852650488 0.841042918
10  0.811944245 0.844109273 0.836334621
11  1.07661139  1.114472614 1.101447952
12  0.075074832 0.070410792 0.075386322
13  2.21486171  2.153897777 2.125095071
14  0.542787157 0.497281725 0.495466001
...
```

I would like a graph with 'well' on x-axis, and the three series scatter with different color unique to each series.

sns.pairplot(x_vars=['well'], y_vars=['plusFixed', 'plusEDR'], data=oneColDF)

the above line of code produce two seperate graphs, but I need it to merge into one

Comment: Where is your attempt ? you could do some search effort first

Comment: I tried sns.scatterplot with well vs. oldFixed, and well vs. plusFixed etc. and it works, but I need to combine them. I'm thinking of changing well column to something like, A01, A02 etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying with `sns` already:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df.melt(id_vars='well'), x='well', hue='variable', y='value')
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Quang! Your solution was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily googable. First try to create a single scatter plot

For this use the standard `plot` function with additional format instructions

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = df['wells']
y1 = df['oldFixed']

plt.plot(x, y1, 'o') # o representing a dot as marker
```

The format string can also contain basic color arguments:

```
y2 = df['plusFixed']
plt.plot(x, y2, 'or') # r = red; b = blue; g = green; ...
```

Don't forget to show the plot in the end:

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: asking a question on Stackoverflow is last option IMHO. I tried googling for sometime. Perhaphs I was not as imaginative at asking the question. Regardless, thank you Dames.

Comment: don't worry for me googling 'python pyplot scatterplot' worked (which would show the documentation for plt.scatter which works equally fine)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal line plot for the entire DataFrame, then surpress the lines and make points:

```
df.plot(x='well', lw=0, marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ALollz! Perhaps your solution is more elegant. Thanks again.